# Differentiate in JAXB between optional enum field non present in a SOAP message and optional enum field present in a SOAP message with wrong value

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, jaxb, jax-ws

As in question I need to differentiate in JAXB code on the server side when in SOAP message optional enum field is not present and when optional enum field is present, but with wrong value. The problem is that JAXB returns them both as null and I don't know how to distingush them.

Axis does unmarshalling in my web service so for now I don't know where and what should I do to eventually modify unmarshalling process, but I am searching.

Comment: Install an adapter which will raise an exception (or perhaps do something less dramatic) if the string is not one of the enum constants. (There was a JAXB question just the other day where I posted an enum/String adapter.)

Comment: @Iaune Axis does unmarshalling so for now I don't know where and what should I do to modify unmarshalling process, but I am searching.

Comment: Can't help you with Axis, sorry. You'll need access to the way JAXB is put to use.

Comment: Map the enum as a string and postprocess?

Comment: @lexicore I just tried to do that, I modifed type of my field in JAXB class from enum to String, then I added the same annotation to my ex-enum field as they are on String fields and I have modified getter method in JAXB class. Then I modified web service code to retrieve String from that field. Everything compiled correctly, but I get NoSuchMethodError when code gets executed. Have you done that before? Should it work or is it impossible?

Comment: @ctomek Mapping enumeration as string yes, but not the hacks you've described. Leave the prop as string, add afterMarshal, inject additional code via code-injector plugin. Or try a custom datatype adapter.